# How to dynamic wiki table columns

Tags: html, mediawiki

```
 {| class="wikitable"
  |-
  |Col 1
  |Col 2
  |Col 3
  |-
  |3
  |a
  |tee
  |-
  |2
  |c
  |hot
  |-
  |5
  |b
  |apple
  |}
```

So we have a table, just a standard table. I would like the table columns to adjust if the window is minimized adjusted to half the screen size etc... For example 3x3 wouldn't fit in the window anymore as the window space has been halved, so dynamically adjust to 2x5.

Comment: That's not how HTML tables work. You will probably need to use some `<div>`s and CSS.

Comment: I suggest you tag your question `css` and `html`, as this is not really MediaWiki-related at all

Comment: So the answer is just "that's not possible with mediawiki"?  No plugin or anything?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I just do `class="wikitable;" style="width: auto"` and similar. For more, see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Tables